# Are Internet Protocols On Topic

Tags: discussion

Are questions about Internet Protocols (like TCP) on topic for Computer Science Stack Exchange? I think they should be.

Answer (score 5):

In principle, questions about computer networks and internet protocols are on-topic here, especially if they are asked from a theoretical or protocol design perspective.

However, this may not be the best place for practical problems when working with them. For those questions, [SU](https://superuser.com/) (for consumer networks) or [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) (for professional/business computer networks) may be a better fit.

Also, we don't appear to have many experts in those topics active on CS.SE, so it may take a while for questions to be answered.